# gparted - can't change owner from root after format

Tags: linux, linux-mint, gparted, ownership

[image: attempt at changing ownership]

The last things I tried reported no errors but did nothing :(

```
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /media/johnny/DAT10
 $ sudo chown -R johnny:johnny /media/johnny/DAT10
```

Comment: What format is it? Is it an NTFS drive?

Comment: can't think of a valid reason why, but try sudo su and make sure its running in the root user's context.  If nothing else, mount it on a linux live cd/usb and change the permissions that way.

Comment: Not the solution but I have a dual boot system so I went in on the 'other side' (ubuntu 12.04) and that saw the drive and I was the owner so I am able to write to it.
Ext4 by the way as it's a 3Tb drive.